# spell check for punctuation characters in continuous text with vim

Tags: vim, spell-checking, punctuation

is it possible to check punctuation characters in continuous text with vim?
to avoid e.g.

```
The story of 'Hello World'  :  <CR>
Hello World!Hello World:, Hello World.<CR>
Hello World.    <CR>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  I suggest looking at `:h listchars` and `:h syntax`.  These give you a lot of power, and maybe can be used to do what you want.

Comment: Is your goal to have spell check alert you when you put the incorrect amount of spaces around punctuation marks? I don't think you can do that with spell check, but you can probably make it happen with some sort of script.

Comment: i want to check a degree dissertation: spell check found many misspells; most punctuation mistakes (multiple spaces, no space after punctuation, etc) could be found with vim-regex, but i think i've forgotten some cases. do you have an idea to catch all punctuation mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it isn't possible to add all those illegal punctuation combinations to the *bad word* list; when I select `:;` from your example and press `zW`, it isn't highlighted as spell errors.

That leaves only some other sort of highlighting, e.g. via additional syntax highlighting rules:

```
:syntax match SpellBadPunctuation /[;:,.]\{2,}/
:highlight link SpellBadPunctuation SpellBad
```

(You may want to refine the regular expression.) That gives you a visual indication, but you still cannot navigate to those errors with the built-in `]s` motions!